# The program doesn't end after output

Tags: c++

I use Turbo C++ and i am trying to do a program on my own. I had a lot of questions and so many errors I looked through the site and solved all of them except for this one. After the program has been run and it displays the output the program doesn't end. Ctrl+Break doesn't work either I can only close it and run it again. Can anyone help me?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>
int n;
void disp()
{
  cout<<"\tPERIODIC TABLE OF THE s-BLOCK ELEMNTS\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"\t1\n\tH\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"\t3\t4\n\tLi\tBe\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"\t11\t12\n\tNa\tMg\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"\t19\t20\n\tK\tCa\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"\t37\t38\n\tRb\tSr\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"\t55\t56\n\tCs\tBa\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"\t87\t88\n\tFr\tRa\n"<<endl;
  cout<<"Enter the Atmic number of the element you want to know more about \n";
  cin>>::n;
}

void open()
{
 ifstream elements;
 char x[200];
 switch(::n)
 case 1:elements.open("Hydrogen.txt");
 while(elements)
 {
  elements.getline(x, 200, '\n');
  cout>>x; 
 }
}
void main()
{
  clrscr();
  disp();
  open();
  getch();
}
```

Comment: There is no line in your code that says `cout<<x`. Also, `void main` is wrong; `main` must return `int`.

Comment: `cout` is an output stream, you're trying to read into it. Did you mean `<<`?

Comment: *I use Turbo C++* -- Why?  That compiler is 25+ years old and is not ANSI standard.  Please read [the C++ info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) and what is stated about Turbo C++.  There are much better and more modern options, such as g++, CLang, or the Community version of Visual C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the incorrect stream operator. Instead of `>>` (which is for cin), you must type `<<` for cout.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be `cout<<x` or `cin>>x` not `cout>>x`.